# Array out of bounds exception but the array is initialized properly

Tags: java, arrays, priority-queue

So I have gotten this error

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at com.xidstudios.pixelarena.pathfinding.AStarPathfinding.findPath(AStarPathfinding.java:81)
```

At that line there is the following code, more speifically line 81 is the second line of the following code. (My formater is set to put the code on a seperate line after it gets to long on the one it is on).

```
openList = new PriorityQueue<TileInfo>(superList.length
            * superList[0].length, new ComparatorByScore());
```

The only array I have there is the superlist which I have initialized:

```
superList = new TileInfo[col][row];
```

With col being the amount of columns and row being the amount of rows,(this is for pathfinding).

Why am I getting this error and how can I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure `col` is not 0? I’m pretty sure it is.

Comment: array bounds never fail ! I mean system bugs dont hurt it .. so some thing wrong with your values

Comment: did you do superList[looped] = new TileInfo(); ???

Comment: @EtienneMiret turns out that because I am using static items, the col was reset to 0, I didnt realize that. I thought it was still 51.